# Not seeing the wood, for the trees

Tags: rebirth

How can I clearly see the lessons my soul needs to learn this lifetime?  I am a householder who has a wonderful life in New Zealand. There have been difficult times too, but even though, as a child I suffered, I was able to self soothe with meditation which I have no idea how I discovered. I have carried this practise with me through my life. Happy as I am, I have this feeling that I am not seeing clearly , the things my soul needs to work on this reincarnation. How can I make sure I don’t waste this rebirth?

Comment: Hello Sue. This is a comment, not an answer, but it seems that you are already on your way to seeing things clearly, most likely as a result of your meditation practice. You are certainly paying attention to the feeling that there are things that you need to do in this life, that you are not presently doing. That’s awakening. Most people unfortunately sleep through their life. How early did you start meditating? Is there anything unusual about your practice vis-a-vis common “mindfulness” meditation? Do you have a teacher who you can approach with your questions?

Answer (score 4):

Work on testing the credibility of these assumptions: soul, I, me ,mine, "I am happy" etc.  Practice [Satipatthana meditation](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/) to get the answers you are looking for,

Comment: Thank you for this, although one does wonder how one may have written this in a way that may have elicited a different response. Although always helpful to be reminded of the nothingness that is this human, the everythingness that is this human, I am still searching for something that this rebirth aches to remember. Although this does not feel like it,  I shall read about satipatthana meditation.

Comment: Welcome! But be careful of this idea 'everythingness'. Don't let it stray towards an idea of a universal soul.

Comment: Thank you. That’s an interesting idea, but I’ve got enough responsibility with this one

Comment: What i'm saying is it's an unskillful notion. Also the notion of "this one".

Comment: How would it have been better to have expressed this acknowledgement of personal responsibility?

Comment: Imagine there many cups of milk. Some dirt falls into one cup of milk. To identify the cup with the spoiled milk, do we need to associate a soul with either the milk or cup? No! In the same way, if a mental process gets soiled with defilements, we need not take it as a soul to know that it has gone bad and will result in suffering.

Answer (score 3):

I dream of a world where the purpose of life is to help others. Reduce suffering and conflicts, nurture harmony and peace. In my dream, success is defined in terms of how much you helped others, especially by doing what you love. This way you are happy because you're doing what you love doing - and you are also helping others. In my dream, this is a life well-lived, not a wasted life.

Answer (score 1):

@Sue_Hamilton: you asked, “How can I clearly see the lessons my soul needs to learn this lifetime?” The way this can be accomplished is through a continuing and serious meditative practice. In short, by training you mind, achieving tranquillity, and then, while in such a tranquil state, opening your heart to the possibility of the answer you seek manifesting as a spiritual insight—the answer which you now sense only as a liminal presence, but which leads to a certain uneasiness in your thoughts.
The following, which is on this subject specifically, is take from my article: “What is a Spiritual Insight and How Does it Occur?” on Medium.com: https://medium.com/tranquillitys-secret/what-is-a-spiritual-insight-and-how-does-it-occur-7e206e02b811?source=friends_link&sk=360f6f222ae0dcca51aedf6c16684b6e

> A spiritual *insight* is never the result of thinking about something. An insight is *“food for thought.”* That is, it conditions your thoughts, changing their direction perhaps, or clarifying their subject, or—in the best of cases—completely changing your thoughts. Even a good dictionary can tell you that insights never come from thinking.
>
> The Merriam-Webster dictionary defines “insight” as: “immediate and clear understanding *(as seeing the solution to a problem or the means to reaching a goal)* that takes place without recourse to overt trial-and-error behavior.” Thinking, of course, in the sense that it is a kind of behavior, is very trial-and-error in its approach.
>
> ...
>
> Another word that is often used for an insight is “intuition”. Though technically, an insight is what intuition provides you. The insight being what comes, and intuition being how it arrives; but we often use “intuition” when we mean “insight.” Intuition is defined by the same dictionary as *“the power or faculty of attaining to direct knowledge or cognition without evident rational thought and  inference.”* So, as I said, an insight is never the result of thinking about something.
>
> ...
>
> Insights arise intuitively, that is, spontaneously and without a cause. Yet, the *possibility* for gaining insights can be conditioned via making a heartfelt aspiration to achieve insights and following a meditative practice with dedication. These acts do not cause an insight to arise, nor do their absence cause insights not to arise—they just create the conditions for insights to arise.
>
> ...
>
> Why is this? Because insights derived from discursive thinking are about conceptual knowledge based upon the error of believing that different phenomena are independently real as a result of having an inherent self-nature. As such they can only be insights about erroneous conceptual knowledge and not about the nature of reality. Even discursive *thinking* about insights gained during meditation can lead to completely false and misleading conclusions. Remember, an insight is a recognition of some truth—not a string of words and references to conceptual ideas.

The direction may be more clear, but the way forward is difficult because it requires dedicated effort to achieve. I hope this is of some help to you.

Comment: This has been helpful. I’ll let go of the need to intellectualize.  ‘Om mani Padme hum’ chanted is incredibly powerful. It changes the energy